# I want to add comments to a text file using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to add comments to a text file using Selenium with Python but No matter how hard I tried I couldn't find and couldn't do.
I tried so many code but not works.
One of the codes I've tried:

```
yorumlar = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('Mr508')
yorumlars = []
for element in elements:
    yorumlars.append(element.text)

yorumlarCount = 1

with open("commends.txt","w",encoding = "UTF-8") as file:
    for yorumlar in yorumlars:
        file.write(str(yorumlarCount) + ".\n" + yorumlar + "\n")
        file.write("**********\n")
        yorumlarCount += 1
```

I'm trying to pull the comments on all posts of one of the Instagram pages.
If you know please answer my question I have to do this code because I will get points from this code.
Thanks, come easy.

Comment: What is contained under your `elements` iterable (I assume a list)?

Comment: Do I beat all the codes? if you want

Comment: Just print the values of `yorumlars` and also post the expected output format of your text file

Comment: I am also trying to do it: D